# How do Google Meet virtual backgrounds work?

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video, video-processing, google-meet

Does anyone know how Google Meet manages to do Virtual Backgrounds with my webcam without requiring a browser extension or anything — it seems very impressive that it can do this in real time via my browser - is this a Google Chrome feature?